# CSS selectors - hierarchy

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table with the class "forum". I would like all p and a tags within the table to have a margin as follows:

```
.forum p,a { margin:2px; }
```

The above code however seems to be targetting ancor tags elsewhere on the page aswell.. I cant see where i am going wrong..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
.forum p, .forum a { margin:2px; }
```

You need to specify `.forum` on both, otherwise it thinks you want to apply the style on ALL `a` tags.

Comment: That worked fine.. I cant belive i didnt think of that.. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lee, no problem, it's an easy mistake to make :)